# Sphinx version for file indexing

Tags: sphinx

I working on full text search on MS Office files, i am using postgresql and sphinx for indexation, but on our production server installed sphinx version 0.99. I can not decide if i need to update it to last version. How much does this versions differ in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute Performance? Not much. It hasnt got much better, it hasnt got much worse. Sphinx was pretty fast already, been no groundbreaking changes that suddenly make it so much faster.

Its more about features and fixes. But the new features allow you do stuff easier and quicker, which in turn may lead to more performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, think i will use old version for the time being.